# How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary using golang projection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, projection, mongo-go

```
projectStage := bson.D{
{"$project", bson.D{
    {"_id", 0},
    {"name", "$_id"},
    {"total", 1},
    {"totalPagu", 1},
    {"idpagu", 1},
    {"pdn", bson.D{
        {"$round", bson.D{
            {"pdn", 1},
        }},
    },
    }},
},
```

}

I get an error here message:

```
$round only supports numeric types, not object
```

How can I reslove this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Go programming language, you can use the fmt.Sprintf function to round a float to at most 2 decimal places.

You can also use the math.Round function to round a float to the nearest integer, and then convert it to a string with the desired number of decimal places using fmt.Sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$round`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/) operator takes an array as its operand, specifying the number to round and the decimal places to round to:

```
{ $round : [ <number>, <place> ] }
```

You may use the [`bson.A`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#A) type to specify an array (or simply `[]any`). So use the following project document:

```
projectStage := bson.D{
    {"$project", bson.D{
        {"_id", 0},
        {"name", "$_id"},
        {"total", 1},
        {"totalPagu", 1},
        {"idpagu", 1},
        {"pdn", bson.D{
            {"$round", bson.A{"$pdn", 2}},
        }},
    }},
}
```